# Remove docker images by repository

Tags: docker

I have a lot of docker images from the same repository, for example, `docker.io/mycompany/myimage`.

How can I delete all images from a particular repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | grep "^docker.io/mycompany/" | xargs -r docker rmi
```

To see the images that will be deleted without actually deleting them:

```
docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | grep "^docker.io/mycompany/" | xargs -r echo docker rmi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`--filter`,`-f`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filter) option on docker images:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -af reference='docker.io/mycompany/*' -q)
```